# Какие именно данные запрещено сохранять в бесплатной версии yandex-maps-jsap

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, юридические-аспекты

В условиях использования бесплатной версией yandex-maps-jsap написано:
**"4. Запрещается сохранять или изменять данные, полученные средствами API"**

Не очень понятно, можно ли сделать следующее:

На некоммерческом общедоступном сайте пользователь с помощью API, в котором есть редактор многоугольников, нарисовал многоугольник...

Можно ли сохранить этот многоугольник?
Если многоугольник и будет отображаться, то только на картах Яндекс при следующем заходе пользователя, так что другие запреты не нарушаются.

Comment: там чуть ниже:  Например, нельзя один раз получить данные геокодера и затем сохранить их для дальнейшего использования. Обратите внимание, что разрешается кэшировать ответ геокодера и маршрутизатора на срок до 30 дней.

Comment: речь про данные Яндекса, полученные через API: подложку, координаты адресов, построенные маршруты и тп; данные ваших собственных пользователей, введенные на сайте пусть и средствами API, как многоугольник из примера, сохранить можно